Error: Shadow buffer full
Since my update to Blender 4.2 I get an error message: shadow buffer full when I switch to material or render preview in both Cycles and EEVEE.
Tried it with simply just a cube and lights. No change.
I'm new in Blender to start with (work with blender since a year) and never had problems.
I'm using a Mac Pro with a 3.7GHz quad core Intel Xeon E5, 32 GB memory and a AMD FirePro D300 2 GB GPU.
Not much but for my purposes it always worked.
I have granted Blender 16 of my 32 GB memory.

Might be related: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/121764

In Eevee, go to Render Properties > Performance > Memory > Shadow Pool
Increase the amount until the problem is solved, but generally setting it to 128MB or 256MB will solve your problem.
